# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los enlaces de cada item de una lista de reproducción de youtube?

Tags: php, ajax, lista, youtube, peticiones

Quiero poner en mi página un mini-reproductor de música. Así que habría la opción de que las personas copien el link de una lista de reproducción de youtube para guardar la y poder reproducirla.

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo obtener el link de cada canción que integre la lista.

La respuesta pude ser sobre cómo hacerlo con ajax o desde php.

Comment: `La respuesta pude ser sobre cómo hacerlo con ajax o desde php.` - Stack Overflow no es un sitio para escribirle el código. Debe mostrar qué ha intentado. Lea [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso su puede hacer con la api de google llamada: Youtube Data API v3.

Esta api se puede obtener sin costo (durante los primeros tres meses) con una cuenta de google.

En el siguiente enlace se puede estudiar la documentación y probar el funcionamiento de la api: [Api reference | youtube data api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/?apix=true).

> Todos los articulos a continuación los extraje del link que les acabo de dejar, hay mucho más que pueden hacer.

## Cómo invocar la API

Los siguientes requisitos se aplican a las solicitudes de la API de datos de YouTube:

1. Cada solicitud debe especificar una clave de API (con el parámetro key) o proporcionar un token de OAuth 2.0. Tu clave de API está disponible en el panel de Acceso a la API de la consola de API para tu proyecto.
2. Debes enviar un token de autorización para cada solicitud de inserción, actualización y eliminación. También debes enviar un token de autorización para cualquier solicitud que recupera los datos privados del usuario autenticado.

   Además, algunos métodos de la API para la recuperación de recursos pueden ser compatibles con los parámetros que requieren autorización o pueden contener metadatos adicionales cuando se autorizan las solicitudes. Por ejemplo, una solicitud para recuperar los videos subidos de un usuario también puede contener videos privados si ese usuario específico autoriza la solicitud.
3. La API es compatible con el protocolo de autenticación OAuth 2.0. Puedes proporcionar un token de OAuth 2.0 de cualquiera de las siguientes maneras:

   - Utiliza el parámetro de consulta access_token de la siguiente manera: ?access_token=oauth2-token
   - Utiliza el encabezado de HTTP Authorization de la siguiente manera: Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token

   Las instrucciones completas para implementar la autenticación OAuth 2.0 en su aplicación se pueden encontrar en la guía de autenticación.

---

---

A continución se explica la propiedad de la API a usar para extraer las canciones de una lista de reprocucción:

## PlaylistItems

---

Un recurso playlistItem identifica otro recurso, como un video, que se incluye en una lista de reproducción. Además, el recurso playlistItem contiene información sobre el recurso incluido que se refiere específicamente a la forma en que se utiliza dicho recurso en esa lista de reproducción.

YouTube utiliza listas de reproducción para identificar colecciones especiales de videos para un canal, por ejemplo:

- videos subidos
- videos favoritos
- videos con calificación positiva (me gusta)
- historial de reproducciones
- ver más tarde

Para ser más específicos, estas listas están asociadas a un canal, que es una colección de videos, listas de reproducción e información adicional de YouTube de una persona, un grupo o una empresa.

Puedes recuperar los ID de listas de reproducción para cada una de estas listas de channel resource para un canal determinado. Luego, puedes utilizar el método playlistItems.list para recuperar cualquiera de esas listas. También puedes agregar o quitar elementos de esas listas invocando los métodos playlistItems.insert y playlistItems.delete. Por ejemplo, si un usuario marca un video como favorito, tú insertarías ese video en la lista de reproducción de videos favoritos del canal de ese usuario.

- [delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/delete)
- [insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert)
- [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list). Este será el que usemos para obtener las canciones, por ende será la única que describiré

  Muestra una colección de elementos de una lista de reproducción que coinciden con los parámetros de solicitud de la API. Puedes recuperar todos los elementos de una lista de reproducción en una lista de reproducción específica o recuperar uno o más elementos de una lista de reproducción mediante sus ID únicos.

  ### [Solicitud HTTP](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#solicitud-http)

  GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems

  #### [Parámetros](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#par%C3%A1metros)

  #### 1. Parámetros obligatorios.

  - part

    string
    El parámetro part especifica una lista separada por comas de una o más propiedades de recursos de playlistItem que la respuesta de API va a incluir. Los nombres de part que se pueden incluir en el valor del parámetro son id, snippet, contentDetails y status.

    Si el parámetro identifica una propiedad que contiene propiedades secundarias, estas se incluirán en la respuesta. Por ejemplo, en un recurso de playlistItem, la propiedad snippet contiene numerosos campos, incluidos title, description, position y las propiedades de resourceId. Por lo tanto, si estableces part=snippet, la respuesta de la API contendrá todas esas propiedades.

  #### 2. Filtros (especifica exactamente uno de los siguientes parámetros)

  - id

    string

    El parámetro id especifica una lista separada por comas de uno o más ID exclusivos de elementos de listas de reproducción.
  - playlistId

    string

    El parámetro playlistId especifica el ID exclusivo de la lista de reproducción para la cual deseas recuperar los elementos de la lista de reproducción. Ten en cuenta que, aunque que este sea un parámetro opcional, cada solicitud para recuperar elementos de listas de reproducción debe especificar un valor para el parámetro id o el parámetro playlistId.
- [update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/update)

---

---

Y bueno, hay mucho más, pero chequen la documentación, les dejo el código para conextar con php

```php
<?php

/**
 * Library Requirements
 *
 * 1. Install composer (https://getcomposer.org)
 * 2. On the command line, change to this directory (api-samples/php)
 * 3. Require the google/apiclient library
 *    $ composer require google/apiclient:~2.0
 */
if (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  throw new \Exception('please run "composer require google/apiclient:~2.0" in "' . __DIR__ .'"');
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

/*
 * You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from the
 * Google API Console <https://console.developers.google.com/>
 * For more information about using OAuth 2.0 to access Google APIs, please see:
 * <https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication>
 * Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
 */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_ME';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'REPLACE_ME';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  try {
    // Call the channels.list method to retrieve information about the
    // currently authenticated user's channel.
    $channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', array(
      'mine' => 'true',
    ));

    $htmlBody = '';
    foreach ($channelsResponse['items'] as $channel) {
      // Extract the unique playlist ID that identifies the list of videos
      // uploaded to the channel, and then call the playlistItems.list method
      // to retrieve that list.
      $uploadsListId = $channel['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads'];

      $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50
      ));

      $htmlBody .= "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";
      foreach ($playlistItemsResponse['items'] as $playlistItem) {
        $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>', $playlistItem['snippet']['title'],
          $playlistItem['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']);
      }
      $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
    }
  } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
      htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
  }

  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
} elseif ($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID == 'REPLACE_ME') {
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Client Credentials Required</h3>
  <p>
    You need to set <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> and
    <code>\$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID</code> before proceeding.
  <p>
END;
} else {
  $state = mt_rand();
  $client->setState($state);
  $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  $htmlBody = <<<END
  <h3>Authorization Required</h3>
  <p>You need to <a href="$authUrl">authorize access</a> before proceeding.<p>
END;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Uploads</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?=$htmlBody?>
  </body>
</html>
```